# How to assign output of pwd command to a variable in python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I want to ssh into a remote VM and run a pwd and get the current directory after logging into it from my python code.
For e.g.

```
    command = 'ssh ' + user + '@' + IP
    command += ' sudo -u vmuser -i && currDir=$(pwd) && echo $currDir '
```

When I run below command from my shell it shows the output

```
     ssh user@10.0.0.1 "sudo -u newUser -i pwd && ls -la;"
```

but when I try

```
     ssh user@10.0.0.1 "sudo -u newUser -i pwd && curr=$(pwd) && echo -e $curr;"
```

it does not give me any result expected.
Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: `echo -e $curr`? When would the `-e` ever give you results that are more, rather than less, accurate than what you'd get without it?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this from the command line:

```
ssh my.server.com "pwd"
```

it gave:

```
/home/user
```

However if you want to ssh and run commands on a remote machine using python, I would strongly suggest using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)

Using subprocess:

```
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "my.server.com", "pwd"])

print out
```

output:

```
/home/user
```

Comment: yes but I want to further assign it to a variable and do some validations in the script.. This works for me too but does not help me further

Answer (score 0):

$-escapes are run inside double quotes, but not single quotes. You are running `pwd` on your local computer, not on the far-away computer.

Try this:

```
ssh user@10.0.0.1 'sudo -u newUser -i pwd && curr=$(pwd) && echo -e $curr;'
```